# AngularJS - ng-click + ng-touch not working properly on mobile

Tags: angularjs, mobile, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-touch

I have both `ng-click` and `ng-touch` on a button used for search.

On desktop the search and the functions called in `ng-click` work properly.
On mobile on the other side the search button stops working because of the `ng-click` I think.

I there a solution to disable ng-click on mobile?
Or another solution to this problem?
I need them both so I can't just remove ng-click.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use third party libs I recommend you using AngularHammer. I tested it in platforms where we have both desktop and mobile apps and is working really well.

https://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/

Using this lib and changing `ng-click` and `ng-touch` for `hm-tap` should work.

This is an example

```
<button class="button button-primary" type="button" hm-tap="myCtrl.myFunction(myParam)">MyButton</button>
```

Comment: And if I can't? It doesn't seem right to add another library just for one broken button.

Comment: Don't know. I started using this lib in my whole project to avoid these kind of problems. Post some code maybe the problem if it's only in that button it's elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What about playing with css?

Set some kind of css that will show the button with ng-click, something like this

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 1024px) {
    .name-of-class-of-button-for-desktop{
    }
    .name-of-class-of-button-for-mobile{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

And for the device with lower resolution show the button with ng-touch, add this kind of css(Of course adapt it for your purpose)

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 1px) /* 1 px it's an example :D */
and (max-device-width: 1023px) {
    .name-of-class-of-button-for-desktop{
        display:none;
    }
    .name-of-class-of-button-for-mobile{
    }
}
```

I suggested this as an answer, because if I understand well, you don't need the ng-click on mobile, am I wrong?